# Custom map UI - Swift

Tags: swift, user-interface, swiftui, mapkit

I want to create a custom map UI in Swift/SwiftUI that is similar to the image attached. A map formed with dots (I don't need it to be accurate, just showing a general overview).

I tried with `MKTileOverlay`, and this is [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mktileoverlay)

Any help? Thank you!

[image]